# Why output content with a redirect?

Tags: apache, http-headers, http-redirect

When you configure Apache to do a redirect, by default it outputs not just the `Location` header but also some content, presumably for the benefit of user agents which do not support the `Location` header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>301 Moved Permanently</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Moved Permanently</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="http://example.net/">here</A>.<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>Apache/1.3.37 Server at example.com Port 80</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Is this necessary? Is there any user agent, anywhere, that I need to worry about that won't understand a `Location` header and a blank body?

I suspect not, as [example.net itself outputs a blank body](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=example.net). In that case, why does Apache do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of programmatic tools for accessing websites will not follow redirects by default without explicit configuration.  Returning content like this makes it a lot easier to diagnose problems caused by not following a redirect. For example, `curl`, commonly used in scripts, will only follow redirects if you pass it the `-L` option.